# Solderless headers?

Tags: soldering, raspberry-pi, breadboard

Where can I find solderless headers suitable for a solderless breadboard.? This is for a raspberry pi project I'm working on which requires the mounting of an LCD screen. I have explored the possibility of using normal headers but it seems unlikely that I'll have the skill and patience to do it (I'm only a beginner at this.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be possible. Just do it the old-fashioned way: with a soldering iron and some solder headers.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution in this case is a Breadboard.  You can get one on the [Adafruit store](http://adafruit.com), and choose between 3 sizes.  With a breadboard you can plug the headers without any soldering and connect them to other hardware using cables.  You can also buy sole headers on Adafruit.